# Merge audio and video in a monitored folder

Tags: terminal, mac, audio, bash, ssh

I want to create a script on mac that monitors a folder and merge the video and the audio.
But if file01 exists (previous merge file) I want it to create file02 and if this one exists I want it to create file03,... I would be very happy if the older files could be deleted because of disk space. But this one is tricky because I monitor the folder through folder action setup on mac. This is what I get so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%Hu%M")
cd "/Users/tomvanwinkel/Documents/Convert/Merge"
for filename in *.mp4; do
    stub="${filename%.*}"
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "${stub}.mp4" -i "${stub}.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${stub}_ok".mp4

    FILE="${stub}_ok".mp4
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        cp "${stub}_ok".mp4 "${stub}_ok01".mp4
    fi
done
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: If I want it to use it with folder action setup on mac the file ${stub}_ok".mp4 must keep existing because otherwise it loops because it a watch folder. Now I want that if "${stub}_ok01" exists I want to create "${stub}_ok02" The video file will always be the same name for one project. The audio file will be updated on regular basis. So if the audio file has updated the new file will be ${stub}_ok02,${stub}_ok03,${stub}_ok04 and so on. Would be nice if ${stub}_ok02 is created then the script cannot check anymore if previous files are deleted. So after project is done. I'll manual delete files

Comment: Would it help to create the merged file outside of the watched folder?

Comment: yes, that could be an idea. But how can the script automaticly run? Because it checks if "${stub}_ok" exists and if exists it stops running. Because otherwise the loop. Sorry I'm a newbie but I can't let it go. If you can fix it to put the files in another directory with 1_2_3. That would be nice. Otherwise I'm going to quit for the today. Sometimes that helps :-)

Comment: See third option below. You are watching `/Users/tomvanwinkel/Documents/Convert/Merge`, right, and anytime the mp4/wav files get added into that folder the script runs?

Answer (score 1):

Creating target files in the watched folder is asking for trouble, so I would create them "outside" instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%Hu%M")
cd "/Users/tomvanwinkel/Documents/Convert/Merge"
mkdir -p ../Target
for filename in *.mp4; do
    stub="${filename%.*}"
    target="../Target/${stub}_ok_$(date +%Y-m%-%d_%H)"

    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "${stub}.mp4" -i "${stub}.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${target}.mp4"

    rm -f "${stub}.mp4" "${stub}.wav"
done
```

Comment: You are good! The third is the only one that doesn't do the loop. Sorry to ask you some help again. If date would be date and hour, would be much better. Is it possible to delete original files in "/Users/tomvanwinkel/Documents/Convert/Merge" after the scripts runs? Only the ones that are merged with the script! There are going to be more files of other projects. Also the older files in the target folder. If you fix that I'm going to dance! Alone in my livingroom because all the pubs are closed!

Comment: @TomVanwinkel Sure, as long as you only run this once per hour it should work. Otherwise you need to modify the date format string in the assignment to `target`, see `man strftime` for possible values.

Comment: Almost dancing! Don't know if I can grade you , give points or pay you. Let me know. I'm going to dance! You made my day! Tomorrow I 'm going to try to delete files in target folder older then one day.

Comment: @TomVanwinkel Upvoting and accepting answers is the currency used here, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to remove file by file in merge folder after conversion. Assume there are multiple persons who going to copy to the merge folder. Then there files could be deleted before conversion. So I was thinking I didn't remove the audio just muted it. So it's possible to check on name and size. It has to be possible to delete it. Now I added sleep 1200 after mkdir -p .../target. But that's no garantee